# OFFSET limit exceeds while implementing pagination for listing of users

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination, querylocator

Currently, we are trying to populate all users of `salesforce` in a `Visualforce Page` with page per limit of 1000 using `Database.getQueryLocator` *(shown below)*

> `Database.getQueryLocator('select
>   Id,Name,UserType,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,Username from User Where
>   IsActive = true order by Name LIMIT 1000')`

As the capacity to fetch the `getQueryLocator` is of `10,000` I can't event directly fire a query without using limit clause *(shown below)*

```
   String query= 'select Id,Name,UserType,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,Username from User Where IsActive = true order by Name' ;
   StandardSetController  con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
```

Now, the problem is currently in system there are around 62 thousand users active and in order to provide the `next` , `prev` , `hasNext` , `hasPrev` feature I need to perform the displacement of `1000` records every time user presses
`next` or `prev` button on visualforce page

1. Fetch first thousand records

> select Id,Name,UserType,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,Username from User
>   Where IsActive = true order by Name LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0

2. Fetch next thousand records

> select Id,Name,UserType,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,Username from User
>   Where IsActive = true order by Name LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000

3. Fetch next thousand records

> select Id,Name,UserType,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,Username from User
>   Where IsActive = true order by Name LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000

***The last query will fail*** and throws following error. So , can any one help how would I float per page 1000 records and allow user to go till 62,000 by pressing `next`

[image]

Comment: As per my knowledge,  best approach to show more number of records in VF Page is to implement "Iterator" . even then you will be able to show a maximum of 9999 records. So, you should reconsider your approach, by combining "Search", "Auto Complete" and "Pagination" Functionalities..    (Show 1k - 2k records with pagination and allow user to search using search bar, it's not a good experience for user to go through all the pages to check records) . Iterator eg.,                                                    http://salesforcescool.blogspot.com/2017/03/delete-checked-value-in-pagination.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the Name of the last record of your query result, and pass the name into your SOQL query when the Prev/Next button is clicked.

Also update the map values along when user clicks on the Next button.

```
Map<Integer, String> nameByPageNo = new Map<Integer, String>{
    1 => '<1000th Name>',
    2 => '<2000th Name>'
}
```

Next button SOQL would be:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM User 
WHERE Name > :nameByPageNo.get(pageNo)
ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1000
```

Prev button SOQL would be:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM User 
WHERE Name > :nameByPageNo.get(pageNo-1)
ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: So if i want to implement the same for account and contact then I have to apply the same logic

Comment: @Hunt Yes, it that works for you.